# Login route is not getting renderd on logout react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react js . Now , Here, what I have is a private Route.

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isFetching, hasUserLogIn, path, ...rest }) => {
  hasUserLogIn = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  if (hasUserLogIn !== undefined && hasUserLogIn !== null) {
    hasUserLogIn = true;
  } else {
    hasUserLogIn = false;
  }
  console.log("hasUserLogIn",hasUserLogIn);
  return hasUserLogIn ?
    (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        path={path}
        component={Component}
      />
    )
    :
    (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: path }
        }}
      />
    )
};


  <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            {this.props.isFetching && <Loading />}
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/:job?" component={LandingScreen} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/quiz-setup/:job" component={QuizSetupMain} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/quiz-questions" component={FetchedQuestionComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/*" component={NotFound} something="foo" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )

handleLogout = () => {
    this.props.logoutUser();
  }
```

Here, first one is as soon as I log In success.
So, In login success I have written like ,

```
history.push('/'); then it redirects to the LandingScreen Component.
```

Now, I do have one dropdown, on change of that I am adding  `:job` param in the route which is like ,

`onchange` ,

```
 history.push({
    pathname: "/" + `${jdId}`
  });
```

So It again rerenders the `LandingScreen` component.

Now, on click of the logout button,

I want to redirect the use to the login page that is `/login`.

So, on click of logout what I do is ,

```
localStorage.clear();
    history.push('/');
```

so with this  it is not rendering the LoginComponent and also route does not get changes ,
But If I remove the `:job?` from the route it redirects to the login I mean renders the login component.

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Component where you use the logout functionality might help in finding the issue

Comment: I have just added that method where on click logout that thing like histroy push and clear localstorage happens

Comment: can you try removing the query parameter  `?` from `:job?`

Comment: Can you confirm whether PrivateRoute is re-rendered on logout and also is the url changing. If url is not changing, check if there is any error on your console.

Comment: Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/login"

Comment: Yes it calls that route I added one  console log

Comment: If I remove  ? then It will not be an optional so, As soon as I login it will throw error as On dropdown change I am adding that param

Comment: Is there anything That I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883021/react-redux-async-action-creator-test