# React redux async action creator test

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am new to the react redux.  I am trying to test the async action

action looks like >

```
export function fetchUserJd() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload,
          }
          )
        }
        else {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
          toastr.error("Error while fetching Job Description, Please check again");
          if (response.status === "") {
            toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
          }
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_FAILED,
            data: response.status,
          });
          if (response.status === 401) {
            toastr.error('Please Login Again');
            localStorage.clear();
            history.push('/');
          }
        }
      })
  }
```

Now I am trying to test it like ,

```
describe('Header component actions', () => {

    beforeEach(() => moxios.install());
     afterEach(() => moxios.uninstall());

    it('creates Fetch Jopb description when login action is successful', async (done) => {
        let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    moxios.stubRequest(url, {
      status: 201,
      response: mockData.jobDescriptionResponse
    });
    const expectedActions = [{ type: "FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS"}];
    const store = mockStore({});
    await store.dispatch(fetchUserJd())
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
    done();
  });
});
```

so here I am getting one error here that is ,

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

So, I am not getting this error, Can any one help me with this ?
And the way I am writing the test case is right ?

To request I also use the token ,

```
headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem("access_token") : null,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
```

My service for calling is like ,

```
export const get = (url) =>
    axios.get(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem("access_token") : null,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ).then(data => {
        if (data.status === HttpStatus.OK) {
            return {
                status: data.status,
                payload: data.data
            };
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return {
            status: err.response.data,
            payload: null
        };
    });
```

So, is it because of I am not passing the tokens ?

Comment: You forgot to return your call to `get` in the action creator

Comment: Could you please update it in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return a `Promise` from your action creator : you have to return the `get` call and it should work :

```
export function fetchUserJd() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    return get(url) // you missed the return statement here
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload,
          }
          )
        }
        else {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
          toastr.error("Error while fetching Job Description, Please check again");
          if (response.status === "") {
            toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
          }
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_FAILED,
            data: response.status,
          });
          if (response.status === 401) {
            toastr.error('Please Login Again');
            localStorage.clear();
            history.push('/');
          }
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: I added the code where you missed the `return` statement.

Comment: Hey, even without this  my code is working fine.This happens only if I use this in test cases

Comment: Yes I know that your code works, but your are `await`ing the result of the `store.dispatch` in your test, you need to return the `promise` returned by the `get` call. Without that, your code awaits indefinitely thus reaching the `timeout`

Comment: I have used this one, but  it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Hey I tried everything, But still it is not working. I have updated the code of the get method could you please check this

Comment: You still don't understand what I am saying, it's not your `get` method, it's the fact you missed to write `return get(...)...` in your first code excerpt at the line 7